# What's a good way to generate levels? How does a game like Defender (Droid Hen) generate their levels?

Tags: ios

I started making a game for iPhone and just wondering what would be the best way to generate the levels? The way I currently am doing it is I can create Level files and then load them in through the functions, but what if I have over 100 levels? Am I supposed to create 100 files?

A game like Defender (By DroidHen) has maybe 1000 levels... I don't know because I stopped after like 600.. Are they supposed to have 1000 files? Or do they just have like 1 basic structure and then just use a random layout function that generates the enemies?

I just need some insight on this so I can get an idea of how to perform this task... If this is the wrong place to ask this question just please let me know where else I could ask

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to tackle this, depending on your game design. Obviously (?), manually-created levels that are tweaked for being "interesting" are best, but algorithmic level generation can mean potentially unlimited replayability (if your basic game design is solid).

You don't necessarily need to have one file per level, though that's a common-enough design.

The game you mentioned seems to be a "waves of enemies" style game (it's basically tower defense). It's *really* easy to come up with a very compact representation of each level in that case. You just keep a list for each "level" of how many of which enemy show up, and how much time to leave between them appearing.

So, an individual level could be something like:
"5A,500,10B"

That'd mean "create 5 type 'A' enemies, wait 500ms (1/2 second), then generate 5 type 'B' enemies".

You could fit *thousands* of those levels into a reasonably-compact source file.

Another option for more-complex game designs is to generate a large number of random levels, and manually select the "good" ones. If you save just the seeds for the random generator, that's a very compact representation.

Comment: That sounds good but for my game I'm not actually having the enemies load up from the top/side of screen one after the other, they are being drawn out to desired locations on the screen, so each position will need to be manually programmed... wouldn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily. Look at some classic wave-based games, like Galaga. There are pre-programmed attack routes, and each enemy is assigned a particular attack pattern. There are patterns (players like patterns), but there's some random variation about when/how the ships change from one pattern to another.

Comment: So what if I were to make an array with pre-determined positions per level but randomize the type of enemies which will come out to those positions? Because currently the setup I am using is a plist with "levels->waves->type-of-enemy->position" and the game will spit out every type of enemy to the determined position it was given, in that wave of that level.